# ruby on rails many to many relation between same model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way of creating many to many relations between same model objects?

The idea is that I have a user model and would like to allow users to link to each other. The end result would be a traceable network of relations and a way to find out the relation between 2 users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it basically like any other many-to-many relation. [Here's a Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) that should give you exactly what you're after.